# MySQL Database for each client

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I need some info on this subject. I've searched around a bit but it seems that it really depends on your situation. My situation is explained below:

*We have developed a system where in a company can keep track of their projects and financial situation. They can create orders, divide tasks between employees, send invoices, check if they are paid, etc.*

Currently we have 1 domain with 1 database with all the data for this company. We would like to use this system for other company's as well, but on 1 domain with the same files for every company. So we can maintain the files on 1 place and keep everything on our own server.

We want to use multiple databases for the following reason's:

- We want the files to be in 1 place, easier to maintain and update
- A client can't have acces to another clients financial data by accident
- We can make induvidual backups of clients data

Downside's in my opinion are:

- If something in a table needs to get updated you have to do that manually in every database
- Could MySQL get really slow after 100+ databases?

Am i correct, and are we doing the right thing by giving every Company an induvidual database?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In short, no, it's wrong to have 1:1 database<=>company relationship. Even giving each company an individual table would be way too much, I think. Why don't you just use virtual tables instead to restrict access?

Comment: If your DB server gets "slow" after adding `n` databases, that's the part where you add another server.

Comment: @raina77ow I disagree, we shard our tables on a company basis.  For our situation, each company has 10m+ rows, so we would have to split them on something.  It all depends on your specific situation.

Comment: Your program logic should be what takes care of not allowing company A to see company B's data.

Comment: Are you sure you want to add multiple *databases*? Why not just add an additional *table* for the new company?  I'm sure you write your application logic to hide secure information.

Comment: @Landon Doesn't sharding deal with separate SQL instances?

Comment: @Landon Adding tables seems like a better option than adding multiple databases. Didn't even think about that. Would't i get trouble with getting too many connections on a database?

Comment: You still just one one (or few) connections, you just select different databases.  You don't *need* multiple connections for every database

Comment: @raina77ow, sorry, i mean sharding the concept, just putting similar data in multiple tables because, combined, they would be too big, mysql has a notion of sharding that involves multiple hosts, that's not what I meant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We want the files to be in 1 place, easier to maintain and update

As you already mention under downsides, what if an update were to require a modification to the database's schema?  Having hundreds of databases would be just as problematic to maintain, versus a single database (with `client` indicator columns in the relevant tables).

> A client can't have acces to another clients financial data by accident

But clients can only access the data through your webapp.  If that becomes compromised, by accident or otherwise, what is to stop it accessing other databases any moreso than unintended records in the same database?

[Views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/views.html) could provide similar security benefit (albeit currently with some performance cost).  However, I tend to create stored procedures and force my apps to perform all database actions through them, wherein I can perform my own security checks whilst limiting all database access to only predefined operations.

> We can make induvidual backups of clients data

One could still make selective backups e.g. with [`SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select-into.html).

Comment: I agree! Good points, but wouldn't adding data from 100+ clients clutter up the whole database. I imagine getting a huge database in weeks like that.

Comment: @StefanWeck: There's no reason per-se that a single database would be problematic.  RDBMS can very efficiently unclutter your data (provided that you design them sensibly, e.g. with appropriate indexes).  If tables start to grow very large, consider [partitioning](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/partitioning.html) them.  If they grow too large even for that, consider upgrading hardware.  If you outgrow your hardware, consider [clustering](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-cluster.html).

Comment: You have cleared up my questions, i think i'll stick with 1 database. But i have one more question, what about searching through thousand's of row's with data from other company's to get data from 1 company. 
We also keep track of what company's do, and we allready have 28.000 logs in the database from 1 company. Imagine if 20 company's did this.

Comment: @StefanWeck: Use compound indexes: first by your `client` column (where appropriate), then by anything else you need.  28k * 20 = 560k, which isn't very many records at all for a large MySQL table.

Answer (score 3):

There is technically no limit to the  number of databases you can have.  A brief search [shows](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,20251,20251) a few people have into the 1000+ databases, I don't see a problem with 100+ databases

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it's better to use an own database for each company. Never in theory but often in practise.

1. Sql commands are cleaner and easier to write.
2. It's more secure. The companies can't accidentally have access to each other's database if an sql query or a script is faulty. You just have to select the database carefully.
3. Later if the database gets too busy it's very to separate databases to multiple servers. Big databases or tables may be difficult to split.
4. The tables stay smaller so the queries are also faster.