# Is it possible to use same PHP code with multiple databases for each client?

Tags: php, mysql, database, multiple-instances, multiple-users

I just got into PHP environment from C#, and I came up with a project in my mind that could help me get better at coding and understanding web app development. I did a little re-search on web and could not find exact answer for myself, but maybe I'm over thinking it.

- I want to create a web application just like a crm
- I do not want to use a copy of my code for every user/client.
- I want to build a single improvable code with the ability of working with different databases for each client in each session.

**For example:** two different users login at same time, but my project uses database1 for user1 and database2 for user2, and it determines this in login process.

I have found some examples, but one of them did not specify which language he is using and other example has different directories for each user.

[First Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13017093/mysql-database-for-each-client)
[Second Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17624155/different-databases-same-site-with-laravel)

Is this possible?

Will there be any problems with it to work properly even after reaching hundreds of users at same time. I'm confused about server side of things and how it handles some parts of it.

It would be great if someone can help me understand the logic here?

Comment: absolutley, i have several projects using thousands of databases and one code base.

Comment: Good to hear that. Thank you very much !

Comment: The short answer is: Yes - which is too short for SO format. Long answer is too long (too broad) for SO. So there is probably no good answer which can fit the SO format.